# Issues with FIFO between a C process and a JAVA application

Tags: java, c, ipc, named-pipes, fifo

I have 2 applications, one written in C and the other in JAVA. Lets call these applications 'C' and 'JAVA'.

1. C Creates a named pipe via mkfifo (have also tried mknod - no difference to the outcome)
2. C forks off with the child process invoking a system() call to fire-up the JAVA application, passing to it, the name of the FIFO file. IE: system("name-of-java-app 'name-of-fifo-file'")
3. C parent opens the FIFO for write only

JAVA opens the FIFO for read.

1. C sends a 'handshake' message to the FIFO via write().
2. JAVA receives 'handshake'
3. C then tries to send subsequent messages to JAVA, via the FIFO.

Here is where it get weird. Unless C closes (not removes) the FIFO FD or if the parent process terminates, JAVA will not read from the FIFO. If C sends 'handshake' then closes, all is well and as expected.
If C then re-opens the FIFO, sends a 'message' to JAVA then C closes, JAVA will read it.

From all of the examples of FIFO between C and JAVA that I have studied, they only include a single transfer of data. IE, open, write/read, close but not a continuing stream from source to destination, as I require.

Implementing an 'open, read/write, close' at each end works but surely, there must be a better/more efficient method - more congruent to the ethos of pipes. If so, I would greatly appreciate any input!

Comment: Can't help without the code in question, but the immediate suspicion is that you aren't flushing your writes.

Comment: Why `system()` and not `execve()`?

Comment: Also, do you flush() after you write to the pipe?

Comment: Thanks chrylis & fge.

code: a little too much to post as the moment. If it keeps giving me grief, I'll trim the relevant parts and post it.

flush: I had tried to flush the descriptor but not change. I even tried adding an additional NULL char to the string being written to the FIFO - no change.

Tnx again for your suggestions, tho!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED

JAVA's readline expects either '\r' or '\n' to terminate a string. Coming from a UNIX C environment (where one expects '\0' as the 'standard' terminator) and being fairly new to JAVA, this was an interesting lesson to learn!

Tnx chrylis and fge for your input!

Comment: In C as well, a line is terminated by `\n`. As you say, `\0` is used in C to terminate a whole string, but this is a difference.